# What is the best practice for dealing with legacy data in relational db in the grain of project Orleans?

Tags: dapper, orleans

I am studying project Orleans. I have go through the samples host in github, there is no such kind of sample. I want to know what the best practice is for injecting dapper or EF to the grain implementation and performing CRUD.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case the best way is to use Grains as front ends to your legacy data. Instead of using integrated grain persistence, you will just load/read the data directly from the legacy system into the grain (just make sure to use asynchronous API to access storage), mutate and write back.

Comment: Yes It is what I have done now.  thanks for your reply.  Now I am trying to inject them as a domain service to the Grains.